# Can't add OCaml to system Path on Windows 10

Tags: powershell, cygwin, ocaml, opam

I installed OPAM through Cygwin on a Windows 10, and it seems to work in Cygwin.  I installed OCaml, packages, it works, etc.  I next want to use VS Code to write OCaml so I download a bunch of the relevant extensions and want to use the terminal inside VS Code if possible.  However, it keeps reporting

```
'ocaml' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Presumably this is because VS Code uses the PowerShell rather than Cygwin.  So I try adding OCaml to the system path, hoping PowerShell can now use that.  So I tried adding all of the following to the system `Path` hoping something would work:

```
C:\OCaml64\bin
C:\OCaml64\usr\local\bin
%SystemRoot%\OCaml64\bin
%SystemRoot%\OCaml64\usr\local\bin
```

No luck.  Each time I open a PowerShell and try to enter `ocaml` it says the command is not recognized.

In case it's just not possible to use OCaml in the PowerShell, I tried putting Cygwin in VS Code.  But again, that doesn't seem to work, because it doesn't seem to be possible to really put Cygwin in VS Code.

I don't fully understand what Cygwin is, but the more I see the more it seems like an entirely sandboxed sort of environment.  When I list the directories I don't seem to have access to the files on the rest of the computer.  This seems really un-useable if it can't interact outside the sandbox, right?  Maybe I'm just misunderstanding what's going on.

Anyway, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just in case, have you tried ocaml.exe? I.e., with extension.

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin is a unix-type environment built to run in a Windows environment. It's not really sandboxed, since you can access the host system, with `/cygdrive/`. `ocaml` is not recognized as an executable because it's built for the Cygwin environment, not Windows. If you try to run it from PowerShell for Windows, it will crash, unless you configure the environment properly. Information on how to do that is here: [Ocaml-env](https://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/ocaml-env/).

VSCode has a Cygwin extension, which can be used to configure Code to use Cygwin tool chains. From the standpoint of editing files, you can edit anything inside the Cygwin environment with your external (Windows) editor. On my system, that's `/cygdrive/c/'Program Files'/'Microsoft VS Code'/bin/code`. Note the peculiar usage of quotes to cover the spaces in the pathname.  You can run it from inside the Cygwin console, or just navigate to the mount point after you've started it. `df -h` will tell you where your Cygwin environment is mounted.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
C:/OCaml64      931G  466G  466G  50% /
G:              931G  489G  443G  53% /cygdrive/g
```

IMO, it's a shame having to go through this folderol to code Ocaml in Windows, but wherever you go, there you are.